# Get each element in next div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to get out of the `.staffSectionRow` and get into the next `.permissionRow` and from there find each `.fieldActive` class and change the content text using jquery.

** Structure **

```
<div class='staffSectionRow'>
    // Your in here
</div>
<div class='permissionRow'>
    <table class='staffSectionField'>
         <tr class='staffSectionFieldRow>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td class='fieldActive'></td>
         </tr>
    </table>
    <table class='staffSectionField'>
         <tr class='staffSectionFieldRow>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td class='fieldActive'></td>
         </tr>
    </table>
    <table class='staffSectionField'>
         <tr class='staffSectionFieldRow>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td class='fieldActive'></td>
         </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**What I tried**

```
$(this).parents(".staffSectionRow").next('.permissionsRow', function(){
   $(".fieldActive").each(function(){
      $(".fieldActive").text("Enter text here");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you're looking for:

```
$(this).parents(".staffSectionRow").next(".permissionRow").find(".fieldActive").each(function(){
      $(this).text("Enter text here");
   });
});
```

In pseudo code:

1. Find the `.staffSectionRow`
2. Go to the next `.permissionRow`
3. Find it's descendant `.fieldActive` elements
4. Run a function for each of the last matched elements
5. This function inserts text into the one element on which `.each` is running against

Comment: Thank you, marked this as the best answer for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

First thing first. You have broken HTML. class attribute in tr needs to wrapped in quotes.

Then You can use:

```
$(this).parent().next().find('.fieldActive').text("Enter text here");
```

1) Traverse to parent div using `.parent()`

2) Find next sibling div using `.next()` or `.next('.permissionsRow')`

3) Find all td with class `.fieldActive` using `find('.fieldActive')`

4) Use `.text()` to set the text.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/spLzpsn4/)**

Answer (score 1):

May be you should consider this:

```
$('.staffSectionRow').click(function() {
   $(this).closest(".staffSectionRow").next()
          .find(".fieldActive").text("Enter text here");
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('.staffSectionRow').click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".staffSectionRow").next()
      .find(".fieldActive").text("Enter text here");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='staffSectionRow'>
  // Your in here
</div>
<div class='permissionRow'>
  <table class='staffSectionField'>
    <tr class='staffSectionFieldRow'>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class='fieldActive'></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class='staffSectionField'>
    <tr class='staffSectionFieldRow'>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class='fieldActive'></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class='staffSectionField'>
    <tr class='staffSectionFieldRow'>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class='fieldActive'></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```